# How to add Selected Value (one at a time) from Listbox to specific excel column

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, listbox, listboxitem

I am using a Listbox which contains the name of folders. I need to select the names from listbox (one at a time, to maintain the order of selection) and add it to the excel column A1, such that each time adding to the next empty cell of column A. I am very new to vb and need help. Below are the approaches i tried.

Approach 1)

```
Sub AddRecord_Click()
         With Sheet1.ListBox1
             For intIndex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                 With ActiveSheet
                      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
                 End With

                 If .Selected(intIndex) Then
                    Sheet1.Cells(LastRow, "A") = Sheet1.ListBox1.Value
                    NextRow = LastRow + 1
                 End If
            Next
        End With
       End Sub
```

Approach 2)

```
Sub AddRecord_Click()
           intRecord = (CInt(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row) + 1)
           Sheet1.Cells(intRecord, "A") = Sheet1.ListBox1.Value
           intRecord = intRecord + 1
        End Sub
```

Comment: Are you facing any exceptions or errors in the above code

Comment: i am actually not able to navigate to the next blank cell in both the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may be helpful to u

```
 Sub ListBox7_Change()
     Dim i As Long
        With ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 7")
            For i = 1 To .ListCount
                If .Selected(i) Then
                     Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).offset(1).Value = .List(i)
                End If
            Next i
        End With

       End Sub
```

Comment: @JuhiDubey its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

First you get last used row from the  excel sheet and finally increment that last row and insert next column value to the excel.

```
Dim last as Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells 
(Excel.XlCellType.xlcellTypeLastCell,Type.Missing)
dim lastUsedRow As Integer = last.Row
lastUsedRow += 1
xlWorksheet.RangeA("A"+ lastUserRow).value = ListBox1.Value
```